# Checking the count within a foreach loop

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I have made a function for use in my breadcrumbs. The breadcrumb displays custom URL's for certain taxonomy categories. It works wonderfully, however, I need help if the post is filtered under multiple categories.

```
<?php 

function customFruitBreadcrumbs() {
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'fruit_category' );

      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'fruit_category' );

          if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
          continue;

            switch ($term->name) {
              case "Spring":
                  echo '<a href="/fruits/spring-fruits/">Spring Fruits</a> » ';
                  break;
              case "Summer":
                  echo '<a href="/fruits/summer-fruits/">Summer Fruits</a> » ';
                  break;
              case "Autumn":
                  echo '<a href="/fruits/autumn-fruits/">Autumn Fruits</a> » ';
                  break;
              case "Winter":
                  echo '<a href="/fruits/winter-fruits/">Winter Fruits</a> » ';
                  break;
              default:
                  echo '';
            }

      }
}

?>
```

This function uses a switch statement to display the proper markup in my breadcrumbs. The problem arises when the post has 2+ categories (EG summer & spring).

How can I check the count of categories to place my switch statement if categories == 1?
if > 1 category, I would just like to display:

```
echo '<a href="/fruits/">Fruits</a> » ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this very easily, just count the array with the terms.

Also if I could suggest something more, I'd check for WP_Error a bit earlier, outside the foreach loop, instead of checking every single term, especially that you're not using the $term_link variable anywhere.

Just checking if `get_the_terms()` returns an array should be enough in this case if you don't wish to print out the error message.

```
function customFruitBreadcrumbs() {
     $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'fruit_category' );

     // do nothing if you got an error or no terms at all
     if ( ! is_array( $terms ) ) {
          return;
     }

     // here's your link for multiple terms
     if ( count($terms) > 1 ) {
          echo '<a href="/fruits/">Fruits</a> » ';
          return;
     }

     // if you got so far you know you've got exactly one term in the array at this point,
     // so you can go with the switch and get rid of the foreach loop completely

     switch ($terms[0]->name) {
          case "Spring":
              echo '<a href="/fruits/spring-fruits/">Spring Fruits</a> » ';
              break;
          case "Summer":
              echo '<a href="/fruits/summer-fruits/">Summer Fruits</a> » ';
              break;
          case "Autumn":
              echo '<a href="/fruits/autumn-fruits/">Autumn Fruits</a> » ';
              break;
          case "Winter":
              echo '<a href="/fruits/winter-fruits/">Winter Fruits</a> » ';
              break;
          default:
              echo '';
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Levi Dulstein ! This worked flawlessly. Your comments helped A LOT!